sol and js file migration
1_simplestorage.js
Deploying 'SimpleStorage'
*** Deployment Failed ***
"SimpleStorage" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:

Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***
"SimpleStorage" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:

Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

at C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\deployer\src\deployment.js:330:1

Truffle v5.11.5 (core: 5.11.5)
Node v16.18.0
https://github.com/kshitijofficial/truffleEng

you should use Solidity 0.8.19.
compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.19",    
    }
  },


The asker doesn't state what version of Solidity they were using. Is there any resource that you can reference or other information that demonstrates that this is a problem with a specific Solidity version?
